# ReSharper suggests the usage of var - Can it do the opposite thing aswell?

Tags: c#, resharper

Resharper does suggest me the usage of the var-keyword. Unfortunately, my new employer does not use var-keyword at all. Thats why I am having some trouble, because I am used to use the var-keyword.

Is it possible to let resharper do the opposite thing? So, it warns me everytime I use the var keyword and suggests me to declare the variable explicitly?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:\

I dont want to turn off the warning or something like that, I want to turn that Setting around, so I will get a warning whenever I'm using var.

Comment: I guess that means you're really limited in your use of anonymous classes then.

Comment: oh god...do you really want to work for this employer?

Comment: I am not very picky. They started a huge project with a terrible architecture and no c# experience, but it's getting better, they started with unit testing recently :P

Answer (score 14):

From the toolbar at the top click  Resharper - Options - Code Editing - C# - Code Style you will find 'var usage declarations' you then need to set the preference to 'Use explicit type' for 'Built in types', 'Simple Types' & 'Elsewhere'.

[image: ReSharper options dialog - var usage]

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a screenshot of the relevant options to your answer, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Lookis great :) What version do you use? I dont see "Code Style" in mine.

Comment: My version, the screenshot, is ReSharper 2015.1.3, 9.1.3, for some reason, guess it is time for me to update :)

Comment: Well, we dont have licenses for 9 yet, unfortunately I am on version 8.2.2

Comment: Then you probably don't have a way to do this.

Comment: Alright, thanks anyway, when we upgrade I am getting back to this :)

Comment: @Jannik in 8.x you must do it in the "Code Cleanup" menu, create a profile if you don't have one already then set [the highlighted lines](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VIi1z.png). Then use the code cleanup option from the right click menu in your code to apply the profile to the file you are working on. To get rid of the little hammer symbol to change a declaration to var [uncheck this option](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OeBn4.png) in "Context Actions".

Comment: @Jannik To turn off the warning you get you [can change the setting](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zGVGe.png) in "Inspection Severity", I could not find a spot in 8.1.23.546 to turn on the opposite option to warn when you use `var`, I think that feature was added to 9.x (As shown in Tbid's answer)

Answer (score 4):

Go to Resharper Options, then to **Code Editing**->**C#**->**Code Style**.

There you can set everything like you want it.

Select your needed Preference or the notification level.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the inspection severity in `Resharper-Options-Code Inspection-Inspection Severity-C#` and search for `var`
[image]

And you can set if var is prefered or not as well:
[image]

Comment: That's nice, but again this gets you the rules that suggest using `var` not any that warn against using it.

Comment: sorry - check the second screenshot